# Capture image with using flash using Python

Tags: python, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I want to switch on the camera flash for my app on windows platform using Python to capture image.

On android it can be done by using sl4a.

Does anyone know how it can be done for windows?

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows phone?  I don't think many Windows (PC-based) webcams have flashes on them.

Comment: PC webcams doesn't have flash in them. I am talking about window based phone or tab. I am supposed to use the camera functionality through a metro app UI using python.

Comment: Ok, there wasn't a windows phone tag on the post, so I wasn't sure. I added one (and it will show up once reviewed). Windows phones are outside the realm of my expertise...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the only languages for writing UWP apps are Visual C++, C#, Visual Basic, and JavaScript.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide#writing_code

Comment: I don't want to write an app. But i want to automate UWP Camera app. I am able to launch my app using pywinauto but I am not able to click on the capture button and enable disable flash.